# how to pass an object to an onchange function? (Select option)

Tags: javascript, typescript, drop-down-menu, onchange, select-options

I have an select dropdown inside a table and when I'm trying to select an option I want to send the whole object to the onchange function. is it possible to send the whole object?
how can I achieve this?

this is what i tried.

```
data = [
{id:1,name:"tasha",code:"T!@#"},
{id:2,name:"dia",code:"ew34"},
{id:3,name:"alex",code:"loiu"},
{id:4,name:"rubee",code:"1234"},
]

const selectUser = (value: any, record: any) =>{
    console.log("selected user details ", value); //if i select first option it will print {id:1 name:"tasha",code:"T!@#"}
    console.log("table record", record);
  }

const column = [
{
      title: "id",
      dataIndex: "id",
      key: "id",
    },
{
      title: "user",
      dataIndex: "user",
      key: "user",
      render: (text: any, record: any) => {
        return (
          <Select
            style={{ width: 120 }}
            onChange={(user) => selectUser(user, record)}
          >
            {data.map((item: any) => {
              return <Option value={item}>{item.name}</Option>;
            })}
          </Select>
        );
      },
    },
]
```

I'm getting following error

```
react-dom.development.js:13414 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, code}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

but this works fine without giving any errors if I set the value={item.id} but however I want to send the whole object not only the id

Comment: I think you get this error because you are setting select options one by one, not because of the onChange event. Try setting select options using an array

Comment: can you tell me how ? @Rukshán

Comment: I have used an array to set the options @Rukshán

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an object into value. HTML attributes are written as string/number.

This is your statement with an error:

```
    return <Option value={item}>{item.name}</Option>;
```

You can pass in the index or id and make use of it later to access your array. Also suggest to use a unique key for list elements.

```
data = [
{id:1,name:"tasha",code:"T!@#"},
{id:2,name:"dia",code:"ew34"},
{id:3,name:"alex",code:"loiu"},
{id:4,name:"rubee",code:"1234"},
]

const selectUser = (value: any, record: any) =>{
    console.log("selected user details ", value[userId]); //if i select first option it will print {id:1 name:"tasha",code:"T!@#"}
    console.log("table record", record);
  }

const column = [
{
      title: "id",
      dataIndex: "id",
      key: "id",
    },
{
      title: "user",
      dataIndex: "user",
      key: "user",
      render: (text: any, record: any) => {
        return (
          <Select
            style={{ width: 120 }}
            onChange={(userId) => selectUser(userId, record)}
          >
            {data.map((item: any) => {
              return <Option value={item.id} key={ite.id}>{item.name}</Option>;
            })}
          </Select>
        );
      },
    },
]
```

If you really want to always pass an object, you can create your own custom component which takes in an object. That will obviously be much more complex than doing the above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JSON.stringify to convert object to string and pass that to change handler then in change handler with JSON.parse convert that to real object